# Can't get github to see my index page in a folder

Tags: html, css, azure, github

[image]

I am trying to get github to see my index page within the HTML folder. I am using azure to deploy the page.

Comment: You mean the README page? The one that github usually displays at the bottom of the files view? Also, can we see your .gitignore file?

Comment: @JonasGrumann No, basically what's going on is that Azure is trying to find my index page to load the site. However, since the index.html file is inside the HTML folder, it cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried adding it specifically

```
git add HTML/index.html
```

Check if the file is added

```
git status
```

Now commit and push

```
git commit -m "added index page"
git push <url_name> <branch>
```

Comment: Yes, the index.html file is within the HTML folder. However, when I try to load the page, it will only work if I place the index file outside of the HTML folder.

Comment: Thats how the servers work. You got to have the index file in the root folder.